# Why does params include details regarding controller and action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Just curious, params are supposed to be hashes containing details regarding browser requests. But debug(params) returns

```
controller: controllername 
action:actionname
.
.
.
```

Is there any specific reason it contains these key-value pairs?

Comment: I suspect that the Rails guys needed those values somewhere and didn't know where else to put them so they *temporarily* tossed them in `params`. Probably a quick hack that we're probably stuck with forever. That said, you're asking this question in the wrong place, you should be asking the Rails guys directly.

Comment: @muistooshort Rails guys might be too busy building all those new features for Rails 4.0 release. I'd rather not bother them. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`params` comes from three sources

- The URL
- The query string(GET)
- The post data often by form submit(POST)

The controller name and action name comes from URL. Say the url is "article/123", Rails will know:

- The controller is `ArticlesController` - Because "article" is the first part of url
- The action is `#show`, because the request is `GET` and there is an ID

Any controller and action can be recognized once you have defined them in `routes.rb`. Remember you need to assign controller name and action for custom route?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I forgot the fact that controllers and actions are a part of the URI.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just speculating, but this might be from the days before Rails was built on Rack. Nowadays, you would just put these things into the Rack environment (and they are probably in there now). They are probably still there for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

So you can query those in before/after/around filters, views (not the best practice), and methods shared between multiple controllers